# ClassNotFoundException on main Application

Tags: android

So I have a build of an app that uses a custom Application class (extends `android.app.Application`) and use `full.class.path.Application` in the `android:name` attribute of the application section of the manifest..

The app runs fine when I install via adb.

However, after exporting it (tried a few times on different phones), I will get a `NoClassFoundException full.class.path.Application`

Am I doing something wrong with `android:name`?

Thought the system info might be useful: platform-tools 16.0.2, ADT 21.1, OSX & Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, there's something wrong with the latest ADT in Eclipse.

I exported it again using IntelliJ and it worked.

Hope this helps anyone who is having similar problems!